# Can't stimulate the shift and navigation keys in games using python

Tags: python, automation, keyboard

I have been trying to automate the batting controls of Cricket 07 using python. Code can successfully pressed 'w' or 's' key in game, but can't press shift or navigation keys for the shot combination. I tried sending the keys using different modules such as keyboard, pynput, pyautogui but it didn't work in game.

I also used the below code from another stack overflow to prevent the anti-cheat system of game but still can't automate shift and navigation keys.

```
import ctypes
import time

SendInput = ctypes.windll.user32.SendInput

W = 0x11
A = 0x1E
S = 0x1F
D = 0x20
UP = 0xC8
LEFT = 0xCB
RIGHT = 0xCD
DOWN = 0xD0
ENTER = 0x1C
ESC = 0x01
TWO = 0x03
L_SHIFT = 0x2A

# C struct redefinitions
PUL = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_ulong)


class KeyBdInput(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("wVk", ctypes.c_ushort),
                ("wScan", ctypes.c_ushort),
                ("dwFlags", ctypes.c_ulong),
                ("time", ctypes.c_ulong),
                ("dwExtraInfo", PUL)]


class HardwareInput(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("uMsg", ctypes.c_ulong),
                ("wParamL", ctypes.c_short),
                ("wParamH", ctypes.c_ushort)]


class MouseInput(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("dx", ctypes.c_long),
                ("dy", ctypes.c_long),
                ("mouseData", ctypes.c_ulong),
                ("dwFlags", ctypes.c_ulong),
                ("time", ctypes.c_ulong),
                ("dwExtraInfo", PUL)]


class Input_I(ctypes.Union):
    _fields_ = [("ki", KeyBdInput),
                ("mi", MouseInput),
                ("hi", HardwareInput)]


class Input(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("type", ctypes.c_ulong),
                ("ii", Input_I)]


# Actuals Functions
def PressKey(hexKeyCode):
    extra = ctypes.c_ulong(0)
    ii_ = Input_I()
    ii_.ki = KeyBdInput(0, hexKeyCode, 0x0008, 0, ctypes.pointer(extra))
    x = Input(ctypes.c_ulong(1), ii_)
    ctypes.windll.user32.SendInput(1, ctypes.pointer(x), ctypes.sizeof(x))


def ReleaseKey(hexKeyCode):
    extra = ctypes.c_ulong(0)
    ii_ = Input_I()
    ii_.ki = KeyBdInput(0, hexKeyCode, 0x0008 | 0x0002, 0,
                        ctypes.pointer(extra))
    x = Input(ctypes.c_ulong(1), ii_)
    ctypes.windll.user32.SendInput(1, ctypes.pointer(x), ctypes.sizeof(x))


# directx scan codes
# http://www.gamespp.com/directx/directInputKeyboardScanCodes.html

if __name__ == '__main__':
    while (True):
        PressKey(0x11)
        time.sleep(1)
        ReleaseKey(0x11)
        time.sleep(1)
```

In game I used to calculate the key combination using a function, and this function return tuple of keys combinations as follows

```
def figure_keys(img, bat, cord):
    for y in range(0, len(img)):
        for x in range(0, len(img[y])):
            if img[y][x][0] < 100 and img[y][x][2] > 230:
                blue = (cord_W[0] + x, cord_W[1] + y) if cord == 'w' else (cord_S[0] + x, cord_S[1] + y)
                if cord == 's':
                    # Shot Combination with S Key and Right Handed
                    if bat and (blue[0] in range(left_s[0], left_s[2])) and (blue[1] in range(left_s[1], left_s[3])):
                        # return "shift","s","down","left"
                        return directkeys.L_SHIFT, directkeys.S, directkeys.DOWN, directkeys.LEFT

                    elif bat and (blue[0] in range(middle_s[0], middle_s[2])) and (
                            blue[1] in range(middle_s[1], middle_s[3])):
                        # return "shift", "s", "down"
                        return directkeys.L_SHIFT, directkeys.S, directkeys.DOWN

                    # Shot Combination with S Key and Left Handed
                    elif not bat and (blue[0] in range(left_s[0], left_s[2])) and (
                            blue[1] in range(left_s[1], left_s[3])):
                        # return "s",
                        return directkeys.S,

                    elif not bat and (blue[0] in range(middle_s[0], middle_s[2])) and (
                            blue[1] in range(middle_s[1], middle_s[3])):
                        # return "shift", "s", "down"
                        return directkeys.L_SHIFT, directkeys.S, directkeys.DOWN

                    elif not bat and (blue[0] in range(right_s[0], right_s[2])) and (
                            blue[1] in range(right_s[1], right_s[3])):
                        # return "shift", "s", "down", "right"
                        return directkeys.L_SHIFT, directkeys.S, directkeys.DOWN, directkeys.RIGHT

                    else:
                        # return "s",
                        return directkeys.S,

                else:
                    # Shot Combination with W Key and Right Handed
                    if bat and (blue[0] in range(left_w[0], left_w[2])) and (blue[1] in range(left_w[1], left_w[3])):
                        # return "shift", "w", "up", "left"
                        return directkeys.L_SHIFT, directkeys.W, directkeys.UP, directkeys.LEFT

                    elif bat and (blue[0] in range(middle_s[0], middle_s[2])) and (
                            blue[1] in range(middle_s[1], middle_s[3])):
                        # return "shift", "w", "up", "right"
                        return directkeys.L_SHIFT, directkeys.W, directkeys.UP, directkeys.RIGHT

                    # Shot Combination with W Key and Left Handed
                    elif not bat and (blue[0] in range(left_s[0], left_s[2])) and (
                            blue[1] in range(left_s[1], left_s[3])):
                        # return "shift", "w", "up", "left"
                        return directkeys.L_SHIFT, directkeys.W, directkeys.UP, directkeys.LEFT

                    elif not bat and (blue[0] in range(middle_s[0], middle_s[2])) and (
                            blue[1] in range(middle_s[1], middle_s[3])):
                        # return "shift", "w", "up", "left"
                        return directkeys.L_SHIFT, directkeys.W, directkeys.UP, directkeys.LEFT

                    else:
                        # return "s",
                        return directkeys.S,
    #return "s",
    return directkeys.S,
```

Later I send the output of figure_keys() to another function to press the following keys in sequence when it is the best time to play the shot. I am only sharing the function which presses key at the right time not the timing function

```
def timing(image, keys):
    while True:
        timing_key = np.array(ImageGrab.grab(bbox=image))
        if timing_key[0][0][1] != 37:
            if len(keys) == 1:
                directkeys.PressKey(keys[0])
                time.sleep(0.03)
                directkeys.ReleaseKey(keys[0])
                print(keys[0], "\n")
                break
            elif len(keys) == 3:
                directkeys.PressKey(keys[0])
                directkeys.PressKey(keys[1])
                directkeys.PressKey(keys[2])
                time.sleep(0.07)
                directkeys.ReleaseKey(keys[2])
                directkeys.ReleaseKey(keys[1])
                directkeys.ReleaseKey(keys[0])
                print(keys[0], keys[1], keys[2], "\n")
                break
            else:
                directkeys.PressKey(keys[0])
                directkeys.PressKey(keys[1])
                directkeys.PressKey(keys[2])
                directkeys.PressKey(keys[3])
                time.sleep(0.07)
                directkeys.ReleaseKey(keys[3])
                directkeys.ReleaseKey(keys[2])
                directkeys.ReleaseKey(keys[1])
                directkeys.ReleaseKey(keys[0])
                print(keys[0], keys[1], keys[2], keys[3], "\n")
                break
```

Later, when the code is executing following are the outputs but in the game there is only 's' or 'w' key presses by the code. Code doesn't press shift or navigation keys in the game.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/waWJ2.png)

Comment: have you tried ````pyautogui.press('shift')````?

Comment: @MichaelBrown yes I tried but it didn't work. I also try to press shift key separately in the main function but still it didn't work.